# Trying to use sympy for a homework problem. I've already finish the problem but I wanted to go a little beyond what was asked

Tags: math, sympy, symbols, equation

Long story short, its a problem from the Gaddis book about planting new rows of grapevines.

```
if R < (2 * E):
    print('Please try again, the length of row must be greater than twice the space for the end post assembly.')
elif S == 0:
    print('Please try again, the amount of space can not be zero.')
elif R > (2 * E):
    V = (R - (2 * E)) / S
    # expr.subs(r, R)
    # expr.subs(e, E)
    # expr.subs(s, S)
    eq1 = Eq(v=((r - (2 * e)) / s))
    print(f'The solution is x = {eq1}')
    print('Number of grapevines that will fit in a row = ', math.floor(V))
```

This is my little if statement so nothing is divided by zero and there isn't a negative number for (R-2E). All I wanted to do was just print the equation when the successful if statement goes off. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the code shown not work? It's missing a definition of R, E etc but as far as I can tell it will print the equation if `S != 0` and `R > 2*E`. What exactly is the problem? Also please show complete code with imports, definitions and all.

Comment: I can upload the whole code in a bit. I wanted a nice printout of the actual equation? Thats all I was really going for? But after I dug deeper I'm not really sure if thats possible. I think I'm thinking too much in terms of a GUI printout and not the regular python output. I figured it could do easy algebraic printouts

Comment: There probably is a straightforward what to do what you want but I'm still not clear what it is that you want.

Comment: I wanted V = (R - (2 * E)) / S to be printed out like the actual equation. So having a numerator and denominator with each part filled out with the inputs in ().

Comment: I went with what was asked on the problem and moved on though. I'm going to ask about it in class in a few days. Thank you for trying to help, sorry I couldn't articulate it well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what environment you are using to run SymPy which is not itself a graphical programme. SymPy (and more generally Python) can be used in different ways:

1. From a system terminal
2. From an IDE such as Spyder
3. From a Jupyter notebook
4. etc.

I personally run sympy using `isympy` (an adaptation of `ipython`) in the terminal. There I get this kind of output:

```py
In [7]: V, R, E, S = symbols('V, R, E, S')

In [8]: eq = Eq(V, (R - 2*E)/S)

In [9]: eq
Out[9]: 
    -2⋅E + R
V = ────────
       S
```

I think most SymPy users would use a Jupyter notebook which looks like this:

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/examples/notebooks/Sylvester_resultant.ipynb

More information in the SymPy tutorial:

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html